# Assigning defaults of nested schema in Ajv

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema, ajv

I followed [this](https://ajv.js.org/guide/modifying-data.html#assigning-defaults) instruction and it works perfectly. but if i have a **nested schema** how can i set defaults for inner objects?
I tried this but it didn't work:

```
  const ajv = new Ajv({ useDefaults: true })
  const schema = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      foo: { type: 'number' },
      bar: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          zoo: { type: 'string', default: 'deffff' },
        },
      },
    },
    required: ['foo', 'bar'],
  }

  const data = {}
  const validate = ajv.compile(schema)
  const valid = validate(data)
  console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
const ajv = new Ajv({ useDefaults: true })
  const schema = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      foo: { type: 'number' },
      bar: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          zoo: { type: 'string' },
        },
        "default":{"zoo": "Default Zoo Value"}
      },
    },
    required: ['foo', 'bar'],
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).